# Eclipse autobuilding Android project badly

Tags: java, android, eclipse, corruption

My Eclipse seems to have corrupted itself/my project. I renamed the id's of some TextViews in the XML and it changed the id's of some other TextViews in other XML files, causing many null pointer exceptions. When I try to rename them, the change the the new name, but then jump to something completely random which already exists. It has completely broken my project so I'll have to start afresh, however does anybody know what could have caused this?

Thanks

EDIT: As I am editing ID's, it would appear that some elements are sharing an ID. Everytime I change one, it changes the other one. I think this is because Eclipse generates TextViews and calls them TextView01 etc.. and it's linked all the ones it called TextView01 together. Now whenever I edit one of them, it changes the other...

How can I fix this?!

Comment: How did you rename them?  I don't believe that simply editing the XML would cause Eclipse to refactor anything in another location.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: @TimC - I clicked on the id in the properties of the element and renamed it there.

Comment: @Geobits - I have cleaned it several times and rebuilt it, but came across the same errors. It's still throwing null pointers to those ID's even though they exist and are on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You could try removing the R file from the Gen folder.  That will force a rebuild of all generated Ids.  After removing the R file to another location, do a Project > Clean to rebuild the R file.

Comment: I have just done this, rebuilt it. As I am editing ID's, it would appear that some elements are sharing an ID. Everytime I change one, it changes the other one. I think this is because Eclipse generates TextViews and calls them TextView01 etc.. and it's linked all the ones it called TextView01 together. Now whenever I edit one of them, it changes the other...

Edited my original text to say this.

Comment: I've never seen Eclipse auto-adjust IDs in XML layouts.  Are you using some kind of plugin to do that? - Edit: Are you talking about changing the IDs in the XML, or in the code?  THAT would refactor across the project.

Comment: I've never seen it before either, it's strange. I'm pretty sure I've not installed anything to do that. I've been editing it in the XML, so I think I'll try it in the code, see if it still happens.

Comment: As a last resort, you could close Eclipse and edit the actual files on disk.  Then, delete the R file and relaunch Eclipse.  It should automatically rebuild, and it'll pull from the current Ids, which should be all correct.  Then you'll just need to edit the code (manually, not via Eclipse's Refactor) and you should be good.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it by editing the code and then cleaning the project. This has never happened before, which is very strange..! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

The ID's were being shared between several elements in the XML, and editing ID's in the Graphical Layout caused the 'linked' elements ID's to also be changed. This was fixed by going into the XML of the files and changing the ID's through the code, instead of the GUI. I then saved all changes and cleaned the project and it fixed my issues.